Sci-fi series circa 80-90s about a guy trying to gather parts for a world saving device
This series features a young guy protagonist, who is trying to gather parts of some special world saving device. (It might be connected to time travel, and appears to be made from see-through plastic or some other translucent material.)
He is helped by some dude telling him where to go for parts, but he faces some weird robot looking creature trying to stop him. Every episode the guy collects a part, and battles the creature.
He only finds out closer to the end that the creature was actually a person, some space scientist and he's a good guy, been that way from the start, just couldn't communicate, and the dude who was helping the boy turns out to be the real villain.

Your question has been closed as a duplicate. That does not mean that it is a bad question, just one that we've had before, and our policies to close story identification questions but share the same answer. You will still get points for upvotes on your question.

This is the Josh Kirby... Time Warrior! series of direct-to-video films.

Josh Kirby: Time Warrior! Chap. 1: Planet of the Dino-Knights (1995)
Josh Kirby: Time Warrior! Chap. 2: The Human Pets (1995)
Josh Kirby: Time Warrior! Chap. 3: Trapped on Toyworld (1996)
Josh Kirby: Time Warrior! Chap. 4: Eggs from 70 Million B.C. (1996)
Josh Kirby: Time Warrior! Chap. 5: Journey to the Magic Cavern (1996)
Josh Kirby: Time Warrior! Chap. 6: Last Battle for the Universe (1996)


In the 25th century, humans discover an alien device dubbed the "Nullifier". This device is said to be capable of controlling, or worse, destroying the universe. Irwin 1138 (Barrie Ingham), the second-greatest mind of his time splits the Nullifier into six pieces, which are subsequently dispersed through time. Dr. Zoetrope (Derek Webster), Irwin's rival and the greatest mind of his time, seeks to retrieve and reassemble the device with the help of his time traveling power armor, with Irwin following in his "time pod" to beat his rival to the pieces.
The chase leads them both to 1995, where they encounter 14-year-old Josh Kirby. After a brief conflict, Zoetrope flees into the time stream with a piece of the Nullifier that landed in Kirby's garden, and Irwin gives chase, only to bring Josh along for the ride by accident. Irwin explains the Nullifier is an indestructible weapon he scattered across time to prevent Zoetrope using it to wipe out the universe. Unable to return to his home era, Josh accompanies Irwin, his alien companion Prism and later, half-human warrior Azabeth Siege (Jennifer Burns), in the race to collect the Nullifier pieces.


As noted above, the plot involves two time-travelling scientists (one good, one evil) from the 25th century competing to find the six pieces of the Nullifier, an alien device capable of controlling or destroying the universe. The pieces of  the Nullifier have a translucent quality and have been transported to different locations and time periods.
A boy from the 1990s named Josh Kirby ends up travelling with and assisting what appears to be the good scientist throughout most of the series, but eventually realises he was the bad guy all along. The scientist who was initially presented as the bad guy (but is actually good) is mostly shown wearing power armour, giving him an evil robot look.




Oh my god, words fail to express how much Im grateful to you, Ive been dying to scratch that itch for well over 10 years I think,, thank you very much.  feel like that river god from Spirited away, when the girl pulled all that dirt and junk from him. Wohooo!
